# Function return onchange not working

Tags: javascript

I have an select option menu which I want to use for multiple functions, but instead of wrapping this code around each function I thought way an I not making a variable outside of it so I can use that. Now I am trying to that with returning the variable and calling that function but it only works the first one and isn't being triggered when I select an other option.

what is the best way to achieve this?

```
<select id="level_select" onchange="LevelName()">
                    <option select disabled>Select Level</option>
                    <option value="2d" id="high_water_pass_1">Highwater Pass 1</option>
                    <option value="2e" id="high_water_pass_2">Highwater Pass 2</option>
</select>

var name = LevelName();

function LevelName() {
    level = $('#level_select').find(":selected").attr("id");
    return level;
}

console.log(name);
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you change the selected option? You're returning a value but nothing is using that return value.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gdb2xod8/2/.

I really didn't change anything except for the location of the script itself, Click the javascript gear, and you'll notice I've put it in the head

You need to put your script before your html, the head is a good location:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
  //script here, or better, reference your script in the src attribute
  var name = LevelName();

  function LevelName() {
    level = $('#level_select').find(":selected").attr("id");
    console.log(level)
    return level;
  }

  console.log(name);
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <select id="level_select" onchange="LevelName()">
    <option selected disabled>Select Level</option>
    <option value="2d" id="high_water_pass_1">Highwater   Pass 1</option>
    <option value="2e" id="high_water_pass_2">Highwater Pass 2</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, I changed your "select" attribute to "selected". Should give you the behavior you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `console.log` inside your function:

```
function LevelName() {
   level = $('#level_select').find(":selected").attr("id");
   console.log(level);
   return level;
}
```

Your `console.log` is triggered once actually.